# Detect login shell from Vim script

Tags: vim

How can I find out if Vim is executed in a login shell? I use the molokai theme for vim which provides really nice colors when I use GVim or a run vim in gnome-terminal, but I tried it in a login shell (after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>) and it doesn't look good. What I want to do is to change the theme if I am in a session like this. The vim t_Co variable isn't useful as in both cases the terminal is reporting 256 colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used this in the past:

```
"Set the default color
color evening

"Use molokai if it's gvim or in xterm or similar
if has("gui_running") || &term == "xterm" || &term == "screen"
    color molokai
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you know how many colors are supported by your TTY?

The consoles available with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> don't support 256 colors here (Ubuntu 10.10).

`$ echo $TERM` returns `linux` and setting it to other classic values like `xterm` or `xterm-256color` makes it go crazy with highlighting, typing and navigation.

So I think you should consider these TTYs as 8 colors and use Matt Rogers' snippet to load a 8 colors capable colorscheme by default and a 256 colors one if possible.